# need to find peak duration of the data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science, peak-detection

I have a stream of data in a csv file that signifies the time with date in the 1st column and value in the 2nd column.  The data is plotted below. I need to write an algorithm that gives me an array with time according to how long the peak lasted

**here is the graph**

[image: graph of the data zoomed]
**here is some of the data from the csv file**

```
Column1,Column2
2023-03-14 14:00:59.0,195.80
2023-03-14 14:02:06.0,174.20
2023-03-14 14:03:14.0,156.76
2023-03-14 14:04:21.0,142.36
2023-03-14 14:05:29.0,131.00
2023-03-14 14:06:37.0,122.00
2023-03-14 14:07:44.0,114.91
2023-03-14 14:08:52.0,109.18
2023-03-14 14:10:00.0,104.56
2023-03-14 14:11:07.0,100.74
2023-03-14 14:12:15.0,97.93
2023-03-14 14:13:22.0,95.45
2023-03-14 14:14:30.0,93.43
2023-03-14 14:15:37.0,91.85
2023-03-14 14:16:45.0,90.73
2023-03-14 14:17:53.0,89.49
2023-03-14 14:19:00.0,88.59
2023-03-14 14:20:08.0,87.91
2023-03-14 14:21:15.0,87.13
2023-03-14 14:22:23.0,86.68
2023-03-14 14:23:30.0,86.23
2023-03-14 14:24:38.0,86.23
2023-03-14 14:25:45.0,108.61
2023-03-14 14:26:53.0,142.70
2023-03-14 14:28:01.0,175.89
2023-03-14 14:29:08.0,203.79
2023-03-14 14:30:16.0,225.84
2023-03-14 14:31:23.0,241.25
2023-03-14 14:32:31.0,253.29
2023-03-14 14:33:39.0,262.18
2023-03-14 14:34:46.0,262.29
2023-03-14 14:35:54.0,262.29
2023-03-14 14:37:01.0,262.29
2023-03-14 14:38:09.0,260.83
2023-03-14 14:39:16.0,235.51
2023-03-14 14:40:24.0,208.85
2023-03-14 14:41:31.0,185.45
2023-03-14 14:42:39.0,166.33
```

[image: some data from csv file]

this is my code for peak detection which is not working properly

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime


# Read the data from the CSV file
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')

# Convert the first column to datetime format
df['Column1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Column1'])

# Convert the second column to numeric type
df['Column2'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Column2'])

# Find the peaks using numpy
diff1 = np.diff(df['Column2'])
diff2 = np.diff(np.sign(diff1))
peaks, = np.where(diff2 < 0)


peak_durations = np.zeros(len(peaks), dtype=float)
start_times = np.zeros(len(peaks), dtype='datetime64[m]')
for i, peak_index in enumerate(peaks):
    start_index = np.argmax(df['Column2'][:peak_index]) # Index of start of peak
    end_index = np.argmin(df['Column2'][peak_index:]) + peak_index # Index of end of peak
    duration_minutes = (df['Column1'][end_index] - df['Column1'][start_index]).total_seconds() / 60
    peak_durations[i] = duration_minutes
    start_times[i] = df['Column1'][start_index]

# Convert start times to desired string format
start_times_str = [np.datetime_as_string(dt, unit='ms') for dt in start_times]

# Combine start times and durations into a 2-dimensional array
peaks_info = np.vstack((start_times_str, peak_durations)).T
```

print(peaks_info)

**the result i am getting**

```
[['2023-03-14T14:32:00.000' '189.15']
 ['2023-03-14T14:34:00.000' '186.9']
 ['2023-03-14T14:34:00.000' '186.9']
 ['2023-03-14T14:34:00.000' '186.9']
 ['2023-03-14T14:34:00.000' '186.9']
 ['2023-03-14T14:34:00.000' '186.9']
 ['2023-03-14T14:34:00.000' '186.9']
 ['2023-03-14T14:34:00.000' '186.9']
 ['2023-03-14T14:34:00.000' '186.9']
 ['2023-03-14T14:34:00.000' '186.9']
 ['2023-03-14T14:34:00.000' '552.3166666666667']
 ['2023-03-14T14:34:00.000' '552.3166666666667']
 ['2023-03-14T14:34:00.000' '552.3166666666667']
 ['2023-03-14T14:34:00.000' '552.3166666666667']
 ['2023-03-14T14:34:00.000' '552.3166666666667']
 ['2023-03-14T14:34:00.000' '552.3166666666667']
 ['2023-03-14T14:34:00.000' '552.3166666666667']
 ['2023-03-14T14:34:00.000' '552.3166666666667']
 ['2023-03-14T14:34:00.000' '552.3166666666667']
 ['2023-03-14T14:34:00.000' '552.3166666666667']
 ['2023-03-14T14:34:00.000' '552.3166666666667']
 ['2023-03-14T14:34:00.000' '552.3166666666667']
 ['2023-03-14T14:34:00.000' '552.3166666666667']
 ['2023-03-14T14:34:00.000' '552.3166666666667']
 ['2023-03-14T14:34:00.000' '552.3166666666667']
 ['2023-03-14T14:34:00.000' '552.3166666666667']
 ['2023-03-14T14:34:00.000' '552.3166666666667']
 ['2023-03-14T14:34:00.000' '552.3166666666667']
 ['2023-03-14T14:34:00.000' '561.3333333333334']]
```

the result i expect is

```
this is the responce i am getting
     [datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 14, 14, 34) 186.9]
     [datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 14, 14, 34) 186.9]
    
    
    
    i want it to be [(2023 03 14 14 31 00.00) 28 mins]
    
    im this 1st part is date and time for start of the peak and 2nd value is duration of the peak
```

note: i cant add the csv file here

Comment: Please add a sample of your dataframe as text to the question. Also, add the results you expected.

Comment: i have edited the required fields u requested

Comment: Have you had a look at `scipy.signal.find_peaks` ?